# How to monitor the log file of Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, logging

I have a Rails application, and run it with Nginx and Passenger, for maintanence the application, we need to monitor the log file, and email to developer team when there is any exception existed, is there any gems can do this thing, or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/download) for monitoring and notification.  It's free for up to 500M/day.

Comment: Definitely +1 for Splunk. I've used them in the past, and they're really quite powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Airbrake](http://airbrake.io/). It's awesome, easy, and there are free options available for development.